# Making Functions For Movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, function, movieclip

I'm trying to create a function that modifies all of my `movieclips`.

This is what I have tried, but it's not working:

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i<50;i++) {

checkLine(this["line" + i + "_mc"]);

}
```

my movieclips are all on the stage and have instance names of line0_mc, line1_mc, up until line_49mc. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need to show more code. What does `checkLine()` do? And does it do nothing at all, or just something different than intended?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to put each MovieClip in an array for better accessibility.